# How to do sequency sounds using Adobe Flash (Animate) HTML5 Canvas Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas, soundjs, preloadjs

I want to play sequency sounds in one frame. I tried a lot of methods, but the sounds generally are mixing or colliding.

Main idea is that there is a queue which is like playlist and automatically pop it in this queue after the playing sound or it is completed.

How can I do to implement my idea? Is there any example code using createjs library?

Thanks for helpings.

**EDIT:**

```
init();
function init() {
        if (!createjs.Sound.initializeDefaultPlugins()) {
            return;
        }
        var audioPath = "sounds/";
        var sounds = [
            {id:"music", src:"1.mp3"},
            {id:"music2", src:"2.mp3"},
        ];

        createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["ogg"];   // add other extensions to try loading if the src file extension is not supported
        createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", createjs.proxy(handleLoadComplete, this)); // add an event listener for when load is completed
        createjs.Sound.registerSounds(sounds, audioPath);
    }
    var instance;
    var positionInterval;
    var seeking = false;
    function handleLoadComplete(event) {
        console.log("Preloaded:", event.id, event.src);
        instance = createjs.Sound.play(event.src);
        instance.addEventListener("complete", function () {
            clearInterval(positionInterval);
            console.log("completeFunction enter");
        });

    }
```

Comment: It's best to include a minimal example of what you have tried so far to attract answers from knowledgeable people.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer I added code. Thank you for feedback.